# Problem with Overleaf typing interface

Tags: editors, overleaf

I am not sure if this should be asked here, but since I do not know the problem, I decided to give this a shot.[image]

Basically as I type, there is that weird black column bar appearing between the source text and compiled text (see below), which really makes it hard to type because I cannot see parts of the paragraph. However, this fixes itself when I press arrow buttons e.g. as I go down different paragraphs. When I start typing again, this will appear again.

I am not sure if it is something wrong with Overleaf, a setting I have, or something else.

Comment: This is related to an upstream issue in the Ace editor library: https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/3817#issuecomment-501437781